# Perceptron Learning - Input Intuition in Weight Update

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I've been trying to teach myself how to create perceptrons, and I'm mostly following quite well. The only issue I have encountered so far is understanding what the intuition behind the presence of the input is in the weight update of a perceptron:

change in weight = learning rate * error * input

I have been following [this link](http://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/linear-gradient-derivative.html), but it doesn't explain its presence, and neither does the book Neural Network Programming with Java. I'm convinced the rationale is simple, but I can't figure it out. I appreciate any help - thanks!

EDIT: My tentative explanation is that the input going into the weight is used in the product since it determines how important it is for the whole perceptron, compared to the other inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about "importance" of the input, however can be to some extent interpreted this way. It simply follows directly from the analysis of the **gradient** of the function. Differentiate your cost function and you will end up with the input signal as part of the derivative. Why is it there? Because derivative depends on it, depends on the direction mostly (thus - sign of the input).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So it is the direct consequence of the derivative of the cost function?